# Getting more records after filtering in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I apply multiple filters after each other in my dataset. But after applying the 3rd filter i get more records.
How is this possible? Any ideas?

For first two filters i crated separate dataframes and then added them together. And then appliedthe 3rd filter but it didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so where is your sample data ? what are the filters ?